# How to integrate git into Windows application

Tags: java, windows, bash, git, shell

My `Linux`-based `C++` server (central document repository) uses git to manipulate file that it and receives from clients. `Git` is being used by executing standard `git` shell commands from the server application.
Now I develop a `Java` client that is intended to be used on `Windows` machines.
Client's network only accepts emails (it is heavily firewalled) so the server generates a diff patch file that should be applied on the client's side.

I'm not really a `Windows` user so this whole git bash thing confused me. How to I execute  `git` commands from windows application? Similar to `system("git add .")`, but for `Java` and with security and error checking.
I read there are git libraries but a failed to find if they support applying patch files.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get you completely right, but if you are looking for a way to master git through Java, I would suggest to have a look at [JGit](https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/). It's the Java implementation for git that is e.g. used within the Eclipse IDE.

JGit also offers the [ApplyCommand](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/5.1.3.201810200350-r/apidocs/index.html) which suits your need for applying patch files.

There are [several](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JGit/article.html) [tutorials](https://www.baeldung.com/jgit) to be found across the web.